# how to create a json object from the last insert to sqLite AND a database browser for sqlite of iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, sqlite, cocoa-touch

i got 2 main question.

First one; is there any database browser for sqlite that i'm using in my iOS application?

The second question - big one - is a bit complicated.

```
-(BOOL)createDB{
    NSString *docsDir;
    NSArray *dirPaths;
    // Get the documents directory
    dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains
    (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    docsDir = dirPaths[0];
    // Build the path to the database file
    databasePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:
                    [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"insider.db"]];
    BOOL isSuccess = YES;
    NSFileManager *filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath: databasePath ] == NO)
    {
        const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
        if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &database) == SQLITE_OK)
        {

            char *errMsg;
            const char *sql_stmt =
            "create table if not exists userInfo (device_token text primary key, device_type text, carrier text, app_version text,os_version text, first_name text, last_name text,last_viewed_item text, last_added_item text, last_item_price_tag text, name_entered integer, login_screen integer, item_detailed_screen integer )";
            if (sqlite3_exec(database, sql_stmt, NULL, NULL, &errMsg)
                != SQLITE_OK)
            {
                isSuccess = NO;
                NSLog(@"Failed to create table");
            }
            sqlite3_close(database);
            return  isSuccess;
        }
        else {
            isSuccess = NO;
            NSLog(@"Failed to open/create database");
        }
    }
    return isSuccess;
}
```

this is my createDB method that i call it my applicationDIdBecome active,

and i have several methods to get the items that will be saved to my database one of them ;

```
-(BOOL)getUserFirstName:(NSString *)firstName {


    NSLog(@"User's first name is this %@",firstName);


    const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &database) == SQLITE_OK)
    {

        NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into userInfo (first_name) values (\"%@\")", firstName];

        const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];
        sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, insert_stmt,-1, &statement, NULL);
        if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
        {
            return YES;
        }
        else {
            return NO;
        }
        sqlite3_reset(statement);
    }
    return NO;

}
```

i have a lot of these kind of methods ( for each columns in my create table statement)

What i want is this;

I have a backend that use mysql as database.

I need to make the last insertion row and make it JSON format so I can manipulate it and write it to my backend server.

How can i do this?

Thanks in advance.

Cheres.

Comment: If this is your first web service project, I might suggest checking out Wenderlich's [How to Write a Simple MySQL Web Service for iOS app](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2941/how-to-write-a-simple-phpmysql-web-service-for-an-ios-app) and [How to Write a iOS App that Uses a Web Service](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2965/how-to-write-an-ios-app-that-uses-a-web-service). The latter uses the now-obsolete ASIHTTPRequest (many would prefer AFNetworking nowadays), but it might still be a good introduction to the mating rituals between iOS apps and back-end MySQL databases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Regarding SQLite tool, the database format is binary compatible across platforms. So you can just run the app in the simulator, browse to the folder with the simulator files (which varies depending upon Xcode version: it's `~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator` in Xcode versions prior to 6, it's `~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices` in Xcode 6) and open up the database. If your `Library` folder is hidden, you can unhide it from the Terminal command line, `chflags nohidden ~/Library`.

   You can use the Mac OS X `sqlite3` command line app. Many people use the free Firefox SQLite Manager add-on. I personally use [Base](http://menial.co.uk/base/), a relatively inexpensive SQLite tool. Use whatever you want.
2. Regarding retrieving results from SQLite and creating JSON from that, the easiest approach is to build a `NSDictionary` with the values, which you can then pass to `NSJSONSerialization` method `dataWithJSONObject`, which can build the JSON body of the request.

   So, presumably you'll have some model structure that captures the content in your thirteen columns of this local table. So, insert that data in the local table, and then write a different routine that takes that model data and creates your request to `POST` this to the server.

   You need to determine what your web service API will look like as well as how you want to `POST` it (e.g. `NSURLConnection`, `NSURLSession` (for iOS 7 and later), [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking), etc.), but this seems well beyond the scope of this question.

A couple of unrelated observations:

1. If you use `sqlite3_exec`, supplying a pointer to a `char *` for the error message, remember that you're responsible for releasing that. Also, you might as well log that error message so you know why it failed:

   ```
   if (sqlite3_exec(database, sql_stmt, NULL, NULL, &errMsg) != SQLITE_OK) {
       isSuccess = NO;
       NSLog(@"Failed to create table: %s", errMsg);
       sqlite3_free(errMsg);
   }
   ```

   See the `sqlite3_exec` [documentation](http://sqlite.org/c3ref/exec.html) for more information.
2. I would advise against using `stringWithFormat` to build your `INSERT` statements. Always use `?` placeholders in your SQL, and then manually bind values.

   Also, `getUserFirstName` is returning immediately if the statement was successful. So, it's not freeing the memory associated with the `sqlite3_prepare_v2` (which you should do via `sqlite3_finalize`, not `sqlite3_reset`). It's also not closing the database.

   ```
   -(BOOL)insertUserFirstName:(NSString *)firstName
   {
       BOOL success = YES;

       const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
       if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
           const char *insert_stmt = "insert into userInfo (first_name) values (?)";

           if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, insert_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) {
               NSLog(@"prepare failure: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
               sqlite3_close(database);
               return NO;
           }

           if (sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, [firstName UTF8String], -1, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) {
               success = NO;
               NSLog(@"bind 1 failure: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
           } else if (sqlite3_step(statement) != SQLITE_DONE) {
               success = NO;
               NSLog(@"step failure: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
           }

           sqlite3_finalize(statement);
           statement = NULL;

           sqlite3_close(database);
           database = NULL;
       }

       return success;
   }
   ```

   Personally, I'd even advise against opening and closing the database with every SQLite call. But if you do, make sure you balance your open statements and close statements like above. You might want to also test to make sure that `firstName` is not `nil` (and if it is, call `sqlite3_bind_null` instead of `sqlite3_bind_text`).
3. It doesn't quite make sense to me that you're inserting only the user name. You'd presumably want to insert all of the column values at once.
4. When writing SQLite code, you might want to consider using [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb), a thin Objective-C wrapper around SQLite C API, which greatly simplifies your life. When you tackle step 3, performing the `sqlite3_bind_XXX` calls for each of your thirteen columns, I think you'll really start to appreciate the power of something like FMDB.

Comment: Well, man first of all, i can't thank you enough for this long answer.Nowadays most of the users just look for a quick +1 vote but you man, you certainly aimed to help the op- in this case me -For your notes, yeah that will be my first connection tryout.And yes i will write all of 13 columns and than make it json to write it to mysql, can you point maybe more wrong points that i m doing?For example i m not sure whether to delete what i will send to mysql.Should i keep them in sqlite?Or is there any system that will let me know that the delivery was successful.Thank you so much again :)

Comment: It's often reasonable to keep a local copy of what you send to the server so that if you need to present it to the user again, that you don't have to re-retrieve it from the server. More importantly, you want to write the web service such that it provides confirmation when the data was successfully received and stored in your MySQL database. Having the web service respond with JSON response makes it easier for the client app to parse the response and confirm success. This doesn't happen automatically: You have to write your web service to provide this confirmation of success yourself.

Comment: Can you tell me about this sqlite wrapper, where and how should i use it?Another thing, my connection will be one sided.I wont receive data from the server, i'll just send push notifications.

Comment: When using the SQLite C interface, it is easy to leak memory (illustrated by your question) and is cumbersome. FMDB provides a simpler interface for basic database interaction. Google "fmdb tutorial" for links. Re sending your "notifications", generally you want to know if it succeeded or not (e.g. often success boolean, numeric error code, plus some description of the failure if it failed). In the absence of some confirmation, how will you ever know if you have a server problem or if the user had basic connectivity issues?

Comment: Dear Rob, can you take a look at my new question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25713002/how-to-insert-all-new-values-to-the-same-row-for-each-session-in-sqlite-for-ios