# How to insert all new values to the same row for each session in sqlite (for iOS)

Tags: mysql, ios, sql, objective-c, sqlite

i can't seem to understand this database issue completely.

First of all, should i just open my db connection from the beginning and keep it open until the application enters the background?Or should i just open and close it each time i insert new one.

My open connection method

```
    NSArray *docPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDir = [docPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *dbPath = [documentsDir   stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"insider.sqlite"];

    FMDatabase *database = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:dbPath];
    [database open];
    [database executeUpdate:@"create table if not exists userInfo (device_token text primary key, device_type text, carrier text, app_version text,os_version text, first_name text, last_name text,last_viewed_item text, last_added_item text, last_item_price_tag text, name_entered integer, login_screen integer, item_detailed_screen integer,item_selected integer )"];
   // [database close];
```

i start the application with this method ( in appDelegate applicationDidFinishLauch) but during the session i want to save all my new datas to the same row.

but with this methods that I'm using

```
-(void)getUserFirstName:(NSString *)firstName {

    NSArray *docPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDir = [docPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *dbPath = [documentsDir   stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"insider.sqlite"];

    FMDatabase *database = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:dbPath];
    [database open];
    [database executeUpdate:@"INSERT INTO userInfo (first_name) VALUES (?)",firstName];
    [database close];   

}
```

and my other method

```
-(void)getUserLastName:(NSString *)lastname {
     NSLog(@"soyisim giriliyo");

    NSArray *docPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDir = [docPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *dbPath = [documentsDir   stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"insider.sqlite"];

    FMDatabase *database = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:dbPath];
    [database open];
    [database executeUpdate:@"INSERT INTO userInfo (last_name) VALUES (?)",lastname];
    [database close];


}
```

but when I save those and try to collect them  i Got this

```
2014-09-07 20:26:08.522 PushChat[2974:60b] first Name: Frank
 lastname: (null)
2014-09-07 20:26:08.522 PushChat[2974:60b] first Name:: (null)
 lastname: Jemmyson
2014-09-07 20:26:08.522 PushChat[2974:60b] first Name: george
 lastname: (null)
2014-09-07 20:26:08.522 PushChat[2974:60b] first Name: (null)
 lastname: herose
```

i get field values for each row.

I tried to change my create table method and added `id integer primary key,` but during the other insert i couldn't keep track of this session id and I didn't think it was a good for performance.

So am i suppose to make this right?I got total of 13 fields and some of them may be null but during a session all of them must be in the same line.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of thoughts:

1. Why do you have two methods to insert the first and last name? Do you need that? Any reason you don't do that in a single SQL statement?
2. Assuming for a second that you must do it in separate statements like this, the first one should be `INSERT` and the second SQL statement should be `UPDATE`.
3. If you want, SQLite can keep track of the unique identifier for the row for you. So add a column called `user_info_id integer primary key autoincrement`. Then, immediately after you insert your data, look at the `[database lastInsertRowId]`, and that will return the value auto-generated for your `user_info_id` column.

   So, going back to prior point, you would insert a row with the first name, immediately retrieve the `lastInsertRowId`, and then use that as a parameter to the `WHERE` clause in your `UPDATE` statement where you set the last name, e.g.,

   ```
   success = [database executeUpdate:@"UPDATE userInfo SET last_name = ? WHERE user_info_id = ?", lastName, @(rowIdValue)];
   ```

   Please note that that value for the `user_info_id` is presumably stored in a `sqlite_int64` variable (e.g., the value returned by the `lastInsertRowId` method), so when you use that in a `executeUpdate` call, make it a `NSNumber` by wrapping it with a `@(rowIdValue)`.
4. While FMDB saves you a lot of headaches with binding values to columns and the like, you still should be checking the return values (generally a `BOOL` value in FMDB). If it failed, log `[database lastErrorMessage]`.
5. Do not open and close the database for each SQL statement. Open the database once and leave it open. It automatically commits the `INSERT`/`UPDATE` statements as you perform them, so it's very robust.

Comment: i don't have to insert each time, but it depends on the user of my application, do you think maybe i should save all values in a NSUserdefautls and than get all of them and insert in a single query?The problem of first insert and than update is this; I don't know which one will be inserted or not.Other than that i'll give it a try that lastinsertRowId immediately

Comment: I don't know what your app is doing, but generally you'd have some model object which holds the user's data as they enter it, and only when the user clicks on "done"/"save" would you commit that to persistent storage (i.e. insert it into your SQLite database), and it would do that in one fell swoop.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem right, you want to create a new entry in your database with every new session. So just give your session an ID (i.e. a random Number) and keep it stored somewhere in your App. If the ID already exists in your Database, chose a new one. If not, insert a new row. Your ID should be the primary key.

So now all values are null, except the ID. If you want to add/change values for this specific ID, just execute something like this:

```
NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"UPDATE userInfo SET last_name = \"%@\" WHERE id = %@", lastname, uniqueSessionID];
```

PS: Yes, you should open and close the connection every time you use it, and not keep it open all the time. An open connection takes up resources which could be used somewhere else.

Comment: Do not use `stringWithFormat` to build SQL statements! OP's use of `?` placeholders is a _far_ better practice!

Comment: I guess you never learn out. Could you explain why it is _far_ better?

Comment: Because if the user happened to type something with double quotes in it, your SQL would fail. You're also susceptible to SQL injection attacks. Always use `?` placeholders and then use the `sqlite3_bind_XXX` functions (or use FMDB, which does all of that for you).

Comment: i had problem in storing and retrieving that uniqSessionID, as i explained in my question that was the first thing I tried,

@Rob I'm already using FMDB and thank you for that its much more easier and cleaner